# How to make GQLQuery search in Blobstore Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to retrieve the file for a particular key.but I m not able to implement GQLQuery in blobstore.

```
    String key=request.getParameter("key");
    BlobInfoFactory infoFactory = new BlobInfoFactory();
```

with the help of this key, I need to take out the file from the blobstore.
for the information key is similar to the blobstore key.As i m new for Google Datastore.
unable to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer - [Serving a blob](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Serving_a_blob)

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws IOException {
            BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));
            blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);
```

Comment: but How do i compare my key to the blob key

Comment: I didnt get it, Why you need to compare the key ?

Its doing the job, 
User is provided the key as request parameters, if its a valid key then it will serve the file if not then it ll not.

Comment: so then where should i paste that blob key.. to get the particular file

Comment: In request as parameters, you can pass it like

htpp://youdomain.com/getfile?blob-key=key_to_get_file

Comment: thank you so much,ONE more doubt i have,How do we implement GQLQuery IN JAVA,what exactly we have to import and all

Comment: Refer https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries it has sample application

Comment: okay,actually If i want to retrieve DISTINCT entries of a particular c olumn,its not possible by this query i think so